# AVAudioSession sample rates < 48Khz?

Tags: ios, audio, avaudiosession, sample-rate

We have a VOIP app that generally transfers audio packets with a sample rate of 32Khz. For what would seem to be a reasonable match, we've typically set the AVAudioSessions preferred sample rate to 32Khz as well. On later iPhones (e.g. iPhone XS) we've found the speakerphone no longer plays or is garbled when using a sample rate of 32Khz. But the audio session seems to happily accept (with read back confirmation) a preferredSampleRate of 32Khz.  I've read that iPhone 6S codec (and perhaps later devices) only support 48Khz sample rates... but if that is the case why wouldn't iOS override the setPreferredSampleRate?

Comment: AFAIK, CoreAudio does sample-rate conversion as required